# Method Overloading- Does invocation of method depends on method definition occurrence in Class

Tags: java, methods, overloading

I tried different combination of Method Overloading with Autoboxing and Widening. I got stuck in here.

```
public void bite(int a, byte b){
  System.out.println("here in int-byte");
}

public void bite(byte a, int b){
  System.out.println("here in byte-int");
}
```

In main:

```
byte a=9,b=8;
//int a=9,b=8;
bite(a, b);
```

Here error

> The method `bite(int, byte)` is ambiguous for the type Overloading

When I reverse the method definition occurrence like:

```
public void bite(byte a, int b){
  System.out.println("here in byte-int");
}

public void bite(int a, byte b){
  System.out.println("here in int-byte");
}
```

Then error:

> The method bite(byte, int) is ambiguous for the type Overloading

Please explain how this is happening.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [overloading method priority in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590914/overloading-method-priority-in-java)

Comment: i already went through that widening, autoboxing concepts but I think here question is bit different , I am asking about how method been defined first is reporting error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution might be both are ambiguous as bite is calling with `byte` parameters only. So compiler doesn't know which method to be called as widening takes priority. Both methods have `int` data type, so compiler not able to discern which one to be widened.