# Why 'int' by default, but not 'byte'?

Tags: java, int, byte, overloading

Explain me please, why, when I write 4 overloaded methods and call it => it chooses method with 'int' as default, but not 'byte', which is closer/better, because it can storage values from -127 to 128?

```
class Main {
    public static void method(short s) {
        System.out.println("short");
    }

    public static void method(byte b) {
        System.out.println("byte");
    }

    public static void method(int i) {
        System.out.println("int");
    }

    public static void method(long l) {
        System.out.println("long");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // put your code here
        method(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you called it, what was the type of variable you passed, or what did you pass? Btw, `byte` is -128 to 127. :) `int` is considered to be the "natural" word size of the system.

Comment: Integer literals are interpreted as ints by default because they're more widely used, I guess, since they don't take up too much space and aren't as small as bytes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [overloading method priority in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590914/overloading-method-priority-in-java)

Comment: thank you all for answers, it was really fast! now i understand, how it works :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the [**Java Language Specification**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) says so.

Section [3.10.1. Integer Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) says:

> **An integer literal** is of type `long` if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter `L` or `l` (ell); otherwise it **is of type `int`** ([§4.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1)).

So your numeric literal `10` is of type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because default type of number's literal is integer. To specify long literal you should add L at the end. To specify byte literal - you should cast the value