# Java Generics: Generic Return Type Only and Generic both Return Type and Parameter Type

Tags: java

To start with an example,

```
public static <T> T method(T str){
    return (T)str;
}
// T is deduced to be a String
// This fails at compile time
Integer integer = method("Trial");
//Object obj = method("Trial"); // Old example
```

and,

```
public static <T> T method(String str){
    return (T)str;
}
// What type does T gets deduced to in this case?
// This compiles but gives an error at run-time.
Integer integer = method("Trial");
//Object obj = method("Trial"); // Old example
```

Both code snippets compile fine. Which type does T get deduced to in the second example?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Read the compiler messages, they tell you the problem, exactly.

Comment: Is there a way in which we can see the instantiated templates?

Answer (score 0):

Non specified Generic Type is considered as `Object` so returned type is correct in both cases.
So which method is used ?
In fact, the most precise matching type will be accepted first. In your case `method(String str)` as `"Trial"` is a `String`.

```java
// Will rename for understanding
// method(T str) => method1
// method(String str) => method2 
public static <T> T method1(T str){
    return (T)str;
}
public static <T> T method2(String str){
    return (T)str;
}
// This is your implementation
Object obj = <Object> //as undefined
    method2("Trial"); // as mentionned above

// BUT
Object obj = <Object> // as undefined
    method1(1); // as 1 is an int upperbounded to Object

// AND
Object obj = <String> 
    method2("Trial");
Object obj = <String>
    method(1); // will not compile
```

You should check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590914/overloading-method-priority-in-java) for more details about overloading priorities

Answer (score 0):

I am having a bit of a hard time following the question but anyways.

In your first example the return type is determined (inferred) by the passed in type of the method parameter (i.e `String` in that case). Consider the following example:

```
public static <T> T something(T something) {
    return something;
}
```

And two calling examples:

```
String something = something("string");
Integer someOther = something("something");
```

The first one works OK but the second produces an error as the dynamically inferred return type is `String` whereas we attempt to store it an `Integer` variable.

Now the reason why this works fine when you assign both values to an `Object` variable is -- as mentioned above -- the fact that this is the upper bound of both `String` and `Integer`. In fact in you take a look a the disassembled class file using `javap` you'll see that your method's signature looks like this:

```
public static <T extends java.lang.Object> T something(T)
```

Note that all the above will effectively end up being `Object` types after compilation due to Java's type erasure.

On another sidenote, your example also casts the passed in parameter to `T` which is
redundant as this is handled by compiler's ability to infer types.

I suggest you take a look at the following:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_generics/java_generics_type_inference.htm

Now let's take into consideration your second example:

In that one, `T` will effectively and up to an `Object` type -- as I mentioned above. This is still the upper bound for the method but there is a caveat here. This method is wrong as it accepts the `String` object and attempts to cast it (wrong again) to the inferred type.

So for example I can do this (which compiles OK) but produces a `ClassCastException` on runtime:

```
public static <T> T something2(String something) {
    return (T) something;
}
```

and this call:

```
Integer somethingOther = something2("sas");
```

Now as mentioned above the reason why this works when assigning to `Object` is that it is the parent classes of `String` and everything else.

Comment: You still didn't mention what type does T get deduced to in the second example? Is it the Integer type?

Answer (score 0):

The first function in your case has both data type of parameter and return type of function as `T`, which means both of them can be of any type. They can be string, integer, float, character, array, or anything else. The scope of this `T` type is restricted to this particular function only.

The second function has a data type of parameter as `String`, while the return type is `T`, meaning that only String type of values can be passed to this function.

For example,

```
public static <T> T func1 (T var)
{
     return var;
}
```

The above function can have `a = func1("String")` or `b = func1(2)` or anything else. a will be of type `String`, and b will be of type `int`. On the other hand,

```
public static <T> T func2 (String var)
{
     return var;
}
```

will return an error on `func2(2)`.

Refer to [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html) to get a detailed insight into Generic Methods.

Edit to Comment : When a function is being called, the Java compiler automatically infers the type of the parameter from the method arguments. When I invoke `func1()` in my example, I write `func1("ABC")`. The Java compiler is intelligent enough to now understand the `T` type of the argument is String. Similarly, I return a String type from `func1`, so the compiler will now know that the return type has to be String.

You can also go through https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html to study more.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answers, but this wasn't what I was trying to ask.

Comment: In the second example, when you do `Integer a = func("hello");`, it compiles. The compiler has to deduce a type for `T`. I asked what it is in the second example.

Comment: @nmd_07 Refer to the edited answer and let me know if it answers your query now.