# different varargs priority for primitive and objects

Tags: java, overloading

please help me explain this code behaviour:

```
public class Main {
      public static void var(Object... x) {
        System.out.println("Object");
    } 

    public static void var(Integer... x) {
        System.out.println("Integer...");
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        byte i = 0;
        Integer i2 = 127;
        var(i, i2);
    }
}
```

code above returns `Object...`

```
public class Main {
      public static void var(Object... x) {
        System.out.println("Object");
    } 

    public static void var(int... x) {
        System.out.println("int...");
    }

        public static void main(String... args) {
            byte i = 0;
            Integer i2 = 127;
            var(i, i2);
        }
    }
```

---

```
java: reference to var is ambiguous, both method var(java.lang.Object...) in inheritanceTest.Main and method var(int...) in inheritanceTest.Main match
```

I have these questions.

1. Why each code variant Do returns corresponds value
2. What principical differencies between these code snippets.

Really I cannot understand this part of jls a lot of time.  My colleagues don't know it too.

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/417622/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/Golden-Rules-widening-boxing-varargs

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do two methods with signature (primitive, wrapper) and (primitive, primitive) cause the method call (wrapper, primitive) to be ambiguous?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923888/why-do-two-methods-with-signature-primitive-wrapper-and-primitive-primitive)

Comment: Also of note: [How java chooses between multiple applicable methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.5)

Comment: http://geekexplains.blogspot.in/2009/06/choosing-most-specific-method-tricky.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first attempt with `Object...` and `Integer...`:

The reason the `Integer...` can't be matched is that java will not perform both an automatic widening cast *and* an auto-boxing in one operation. That means the `byte` can *not* be converted to an `Integer` by simply passing it to the method and hoping for `byte` --> `int` --> `Integer`. So the only match is to auto-box `byte` to `Byte` and match `Object...`.

In the second attempt with `Object...` and `int...`:

Java *can* however perform an automatic widening cast from `byte` to `int` for the first parameter, and an auto-unboxing of `Integer` to `int`, so the `int...` matches. But it can also auto-box the `byte` to a `Byte` and leave the `Integer`, to match `Object...`

This is not matter of priorities. It is a matter of what java can do automatically in one step - it can *either* auto-box/unbox *or* automatically perform a widening cast.