# How does jvm resolve call to overloaded method in this case?

Tags: java, oop, overloading

Following code was successfully compiled

```
class Overloading{

    public static void aMethod (double val1, long val2) {
        System.out.println ("double, long");
    }

    public static void aMethod (int val1, long val2) {
        System.out.println ("int, long");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        aMethod(9, 10);
    }
}
```

But when method signature was changed

**From this**

```
aMethod (double val1, long val2)
```

**To this**

```
aMethod (double val1, int val2)
```

compilation time error was occured

```
Overloading.java:12: error: reference to aMethod is ambiguous, both method aMeth
od(double,int) in Overloading and method aMethod(int,long) in Overloading match
                aMethod(9, 10);
                ^
```

Comment: The overload resolution process is complex and arcane (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12), I don't propose to dig through it to figure out your particular example!  In practice, it's rare that this sort of situation will come up (if it does, I'd recommend redesigning your methods...)

Comment: In general it's a (very) bad idea to have overloaded methods where the only distinction is between different numeric types.  Sometimes you've got to actually have method names which define which method to call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When using overloading with type promotion, why method calling is ambiguous?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22991150/when-using-overloading-with-type-promotion-why-method-calling-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, the JVM doesn't resolve overloads - the compiler does. (Whereas the JVM decided which overridden method to execute, for example.)

As for why the method call becomes ambiguous - the compiler is looking for a single method where every conversion from the method *argument* type (`int` for both arguments) to the method *parameter* type (`int`, `long` or `double`) is at least as specific as the corresponding conversion in other candidate methods.

The conversion from `int` to `int` is more specific than the conversion from `int` to `double`, so your second overload "wins" in both cases.

For the second parameter, in your original code it's a conversion from `int` to `long` for both overloads, so that means the second overload "wins" overall.

In your modified code, the conversion from `int` to `int` is more specific than the conversion from `int` to `long`, so the *first* overload "wins" for this parameter. So each overload is better than the other for one parameter, and the invocation is ambiguous.

See [JLS section 15.12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) (and the sections it refers to and contains, particularly [15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)) for all the gory details.