# How the compiler chooses correct overloaded function?

Tags: c++, overloading

I have a class with the following constructors:

```
Color(const float red = 0.0f, const float green = 0.0f, const float blue = 0.0f, const float alpha = 1.0f);
Color(const unsigned char red, const unsigned char green, const unsigned char blue, const unsigned char alpha);
Color(const unsigned long int color);
```

If I call it like this:

```
Color c{ 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
```

everything is ok. But if I call it:

```
Color c{ 78, 180, 84, 255 };
```

or

```
Color c{ 0xffffffff };
```

I receive

> error C2668: 'Color::Color' : ambiguous call to overloaded function

Why? How to make it choose correctly?

Comment: Similar to [c-overloading-resolution-method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29090692/c-overloading-resolution-method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Color c{ 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };` is unambiguous, the compiler can pick the constructor that takes floating point arguments.

With `Color c{ 78, 180, 84, 255 };`, the literals are actually *signed* types. So the compiler has to convert the literals. It has two choices and doesn't know which one to pick.

If you'd written, albeit tediously, `Color c{static_cast<unsigned char>(78), static_cast<unsigned char>(180), static_cast<unsigned char>(84), static_cast<unsigned char>(255) };` then the constructor taking `const unsigned char` arguments would have been called automatically.

Again, with `Color c{ 0xffffffff };`, the number is again a *signed* hexadecimal literal. So the compiler doesn't know which one to use.

Comment: unfortunatelly with `Color c{ 78U, 180U, 84U, 255U };` I have the same error.

Comment: 78U is not an `unsigned char` literal.

Comment: exactly! It's `an unsigned int`. Thank you.